# Is there a term for "not wanting to do something because someone else has already done it"?

Tags: terminology, psychology

For example, person A does something that person B was planning on doing, but person B does not want to do it anymore for fear of being seen as "unoriginal" (even on something not creative) or worry that someone will think you are copying that person.

Comment: Could you please explain why you think there needs to be such a word?

Comment: A sentence with the word you want left blank would be helpful.

Comment: You could say that person B _got cold feet._ A derogatory word for such a person is _chickenshit._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This person could use the term "***beaten track***" ([Free Dictionary, (2)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beaten+track)) or "***beaten path***" ([Free Dictionary, (2)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+beaten+path)) in a number of ways.

- I'm not one to keep to the beaten track…
- There is better for me to do than to follow the beaten path.
- Beaten paths are for beaten men. (*[Eric Johnson](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/44215-beaten-paths-are-for-beaten-men)*)
- …